# Linq Include not loading List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've been for a while trying to find out why the `Include` clause is not loading the related collection: I have two classes with a one-to-many relationship:

```
 public class AgencyNote : IAutId
    {
        [Key]
        public int aut_id { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Note Created Date")]
        public DateTime NoteDate { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Contact Date")]
        public DateTime ContactDate { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("tbl_agency")]        
        public int AgencyId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("User")]
        public string RipsUser { get; set; }        
        public virtual ICollection<AgencyNoteAttachment> AgencyNoteAttachments { get; set; }
        public virtual tbl_agency tbl_agency { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
 public class AgencyNoteAttachment
    {        
        [Key]
        public int aut_id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }        
        public int AgencyNoteId { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]        
        [ForeignKey("AgencyNoteId")]
        public virtual AgencyNote AgencyNote { get; set; }        
    }
```

Context class:

```
public DbSet<AgencyNote> AgencyNotes { get; set; } 

public DbSet<AgencyNoteAttachment> AgencyNoteAttachments { get; set; }
```

This is the action where I'm using the `Include` clause:

```
private IQueryable<AgencyNote> GetNotes(int agencyId)
{                
  return _ctx.AgencyNotes
    .Include(a => a.tbl_agency)
    .Include(a => a.AgencyNoteAttachments)
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.NoteDate)
    .Where(x => x.AgencyId == agencyId);   
}
```

I'm getting `AgencyNotesAttachments` always `null` from this action even if I know it's not null, what's going on? Any question let me know...

Comment: Why is `AgencyNote` `NotMapped`?

Comment: My guess is relationship is not well created due to you are using `NotMapped` attribute. Remove it, at let us know what happen

Comment: @octavioccl I don't understand what happened, but before I had to use the `NotMapped` attribute otherwise EF would create an extra column in the table(something like the primary keys of both tables joined). If I didn't use `NotMapped` an error was raised because EF created that column, now I just removed and it works!!!

Comment: I'm going to create an answer explaining you why that happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add just the navigation properties between the related entities, then EF will create the FK column for you in the `AgencyNoteAttachment` table. Now, EF by convention can interpret `AgencyNoteId` is the FK of that relationship, but is good idea do that explicitly as you already have in your model or using `ForeignKey` attribute on FK property:

```
public class AgencyNoteAttachment
{        
    [Key]
    public int aut_id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("AgencyNote")]       
    public int AgencyNoteId { get; set; }

    public virtual AgencyNote AgencyNote { get; set; }        
}
```

If you want to learn more about conventions, take a look this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx)